# how to count only 5 checkbox values in angular reactive form

Tags: angular

i have a form array in which checkbox is there. I want user to select only 5 checkbox value. Checkbox values are then pushed into an array. I want that only 5 selected checkbox value must be pushed in array as true while rest of unselected checkbox value must be pushed as false.

*component.html* file

```html
<input type="checkbox" #checkBox formControlName="Viewable" class="form-control checkbox" (change)="selectViewable($event)" />
```

I have tried doing following. It gives proper toastre when more than 5 values are selected but when we select 6th checkbox value it does not show on ui but it set its value as true.

*component.ts* file

```js
selectViewable(event){
  
    if(event.target.checked === true){
      if(this.counter < 5){
         this.counter++
      } else {
         event.target.checked = false;
         this.toastrService.info("You cannot select viewable more than 5");
      }
    } else if(this.counter>0){
      this.counter--;
    } 
}
   
submit() {
    analyticsInfoArray=[];
    const formRawValue = this.addAnaGroupForm.getRawValue();
    for (let i = 0; i < formRawValue.AnalyticsInfo.length; i++) {
      let viewable = formRawValue.AnalyticsInfo[i].Viewable
      analyticsInfoArray.push(viewable)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, you need to use patchValue() at your checkbox form instead of setting the checked propety false.

Comment: can you share some link???